# Why does (x^0===x) output x instead of true/false?

Tags: javascript, math

I was doing an exercise on testing if a variable is an integer.  `x ^ 0 === x` was one of the proposed solutions, however when I try that in Chrome's console, on codepen.io or here, it returns `x`.  Why is this?

```js
function isInteger(x) {
  console.log(x ^ 0 === x);
}

isInteger(5);
isInteger(124.124)
isInteger(0);
```

Comment: By the way, [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) was introduced in ECMAScript 6. No need to reinvent the wheel anymore.

Comment: Yep, just an exercise :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition is evaluated wrongly due to you missed to add `()` around `x^0`:

```js
function isInteger(x) {
  console.log((x ^ 0) === x);
}

isInteger(5);
isInteger(124.124)
isInteger(0);
```

Comment: happens to all of us xD

Comment: I wish it wasn't happening to me 4 hours before a coding test for a new job ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Scott Beeson: At least it wasn't *during* the test.

Comment: you will do this, i am sure.

Comment: Has yet to be seen!

Answer (score 3):

While messerbill's answer explains the problem, there is another one. This is not a good method to use:

```js
function isInteger(x) {
  console.log((x ^ 0) === x);
}

isInteger(281474976710656);
```

The reason why is because [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) coerce the operands to 32 bits. Better to use this:

```js
function isInteger(x) {
  console.log((x % 1) === 0);
}

isInteger(5);
isInteger(124.124)
isInteger(0);
isInteger(281474976710656);
```

Comment: I love you.  While doing the exercise, using modulus was the first thing that popped into my head, and that's what I used.  When I viewed the potential solutions it was nowhere to be found. I thought maybe it wasn't a good idea.  Thanks for the unintentional reassurance!  (edit: it is there, just missed it, but still...)

Comment: @ScottBeeson thank you for this link - i will send this to my brother who is also learning js at the moment :D

Comment: @ScottBeeson It does: `function isInteger(x) { return (typeof x === 'number') && (x % 1 === 0); }`, though I was already assuming we'd only be passing numeric input to the function. Guess all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

As complement to the provided answers, the concept related to the issue is "[operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)". That page is where I go when I have this kind of problems in JS (different languages may have slightly different operator precedences, e.g. the exponentiation operator `**` in js and [php](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)).

So from the examples in the answers:

```
(x ^ 0) === x
```

requires parentheses

while

```
x % 1 === 0
```

does not.